# WS2812B LED strip interference with PC monitor

Tags: led, ws2812b, strip

As post title says I think I have an interference issue between a WS2812B LED strip (98 LEDs) and my PC monitor Viewsonic VX2458. The LEDs are connected to the back of monitor in a rectangular shape and controlled from PC software by an Arduino board as an ambilight. I have a 6A 5V power supply powering the LED strip.

The issue I am seeing is:

- When the monitor goes to sleep instead of staying asleep it will randomly (from few seconds to few minutes power up) - show up no signal massage and goes back to sleep.
- When I switch off the PC the same thing happens even when LEDs are off at this stage.

The cable from the power supply and the USB cable going to the Arduino has ferrite clips. I also put additional ones on each cable close to the first LED.

Looking for any other ideas and possible solutions.

Comment: Show block diagram with expected signals

Comment: I don't see how LEDs can affect a computer monitor. Are you sure your monitor isn't just behaving badly on its own?

Comment: Does "LEDs are off" mean power is off or that they are commanded to be dark? Kind of sounds like noise on the HDMI Hot Plug detect pin or similar. Cheapo power supplies tend to be super noisy

Comment: "LEDs off" means they are switch off by software. I was making more digging on that issue this weekend. I forget to mention i have one more connection from GPU to Denon AVR with HDMI cable (7.5 m long) which i think is causing that issue - thanks to @ks0ze suggestion (Monitor is connected to PC by DP cable). I have also chromcast connected to another one of HDMI ports of AVR. But lets start from the beginning. PC with only monitor connected no issues with monitor power save mode. PC with AVR connected issues with PC monitor sleep mode, even when PC is shut down. Looking for more guidance.

Comment: Update: After few more days of testing, with only monitor connected i can confirm the issue is still there. It starts as soon as i switch ON power supply 5A 6A for LED's. (LED's are taped at the back of the monitor) just to confirm. PC can be shut down with monitor in sleep mode, and even then if i switch ON LED's power supply it switches on for moment and goes back to sleep. And this loop continues forever.